# Spam issue with Gmail

Tags: email, gmail, imap, pop3

I've added someone as a contact and set a rule not to spam out their emails, but for some reason they keep ending up in the Spam folder.

They will show up in the inbox for about 5 minutes before being moved to the spam folder automatically again.

Other devices logged in:

- Outlook - POP3
- Samsung Email via phone - IMAP

Anyone have an idea why this would be happening?

Comment: Have you determined if an Outlook rule is moving the email or if a Gmail rule is moving it?

Comment: I don't think it is Outlook because the email doesn't show up at all. Its not in the Junk folder or anywhere else until I tell Gmail that its not spam. Then it pops up in Outlook but a few minutes later it gets sent back to the spam folder in Gmail.

Comment: Not only that but it is setup for POP3 so the way things are changed in Outlook shouldn't have any effect on how they appear in Gmail.

Comment: Gmail does not have folders it only has labels.  Outlook has folders.  You can treat a label as a folder within Outlook but does not change the fact it's a label.  So the Spam folder would be a label within Gmail.

Comment: Ah okay. So Gmail keeps labeling the emails as Spam. When I click one of the messages it says: "
Why is this message in spam? You previously marked messages from <email address> as spam." - Is there a way to fix it so the filter stops labeling them?

Comment: Are you selecting the button that indicates the email is NOT actually spam?  The only way to train the spam filter within GMAIL is to use the functionality within GMAIL to do so.  You might consider creating a filter that will force this to happen (for instance marking the email as important).

Comment: I've created a filter that both marks it Not Spam and stars each new email from the address. I went through each of the email messages and clicked "Report not spam".

I also turned off IMAP for the time being.

Messages are still being labeled spam.

Comment: I thought you were using POP3 instead of IMAP?

Comment: IMAP was enabled for the email app via Samsung. Outlook is setup via POP3

Answer (score -1):

It turned out that the issues were caused by the Samsung Email client on my phone.

Comment: Any details for future readers?